# Use jQuery to append response to individual HTML elements without duplication

Tags: jquery, append

[image]I am trying to store the result of each form submission into its own individual HTML element. My code is doing this but it's also duplicating the results. Is there a way to append the result just the once rather than to all matching classes without creating uniquely identifiable elements (e.g. card1, card2, card3).

```
    <form id='userForm' method="POST">
<input class="textbox" type='text' name='query' placeholder='Question' value="" />

        <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
    </form>

    <div class="responses"></div>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#userForm').submit(function(){
            var question = $(".textbox").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/dev/post.php',
                data: $(this).serialize()
            })
            .done(function(data){
                $( "<div class='response'><div class='question'></div><div class='answer'></div></div>").appendTo( ".responses" );
                $('.question').append(question);
                $('.answer').append(data);
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert( "Whoops, there's been a problem with getting the answer." );
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you show n example of what your code is current outputting and an example of a desired output?

Comment: I've added a screenshot showing the issue. Each box should only have one "This is my query?" and one "This is the response" for each time the Submit button is pushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `last()` -

```
$('.question').last().append(question);
$('.answer').last().append(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed!